# How to create li active shape

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to create a shape in menu header which indicates that is selected (active class), but I can't bring the shape up and align it.

This is what I've tried:

HTML

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Market</a></li>
```

CSS

```
.active {
   z-index: -1; 
   position: absolute;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #b6ff00;
   border-left: 1px solid transparent;
   border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

[image]

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Dra/

Comment: Try http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/ for making triangles out of css borders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track with the border. You just needed to apply it to a pseudo element instead of the li.

Full Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Dra/4/

Relevant Code:

```
.active:after {
    content:'';
    border:10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid #b6ff00;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a psuedo element: http://jsfiddle.net/webbymatt/QL7Qr/

HTML

```
<a href="">Home</a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}
a:after {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```